# SELECT * from simple table with 50k records seems to take 40 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, timing

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.logs (
  logid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('applog_logid_seq'::regclass),
  applicationname character varying(50),
  loglevel character varying(10),
  logmessage character varying(500),
  stacktrace character varying(4096),
  occurredon timestamp without time zone,
  loggedon timestamp without time zone,
  username character varying(50),
  groupname character varying(50),
  useragent character varying(512),
  CONSTRAINT applog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (logid)
);
```

When I run `SELECT *...` on it, it takes 40 seconds to return 50000 rows on my local machine. I have the same table on a local install of SQL Server, and that takes less than a second to return the same amount of data.

I'm in the middle of an evaluation of PostgreSQL for our new stack and this is very concerning to me. Why am I doing wrong/why is PostgreSQL so slow?

**Edit:**

Here's what I get from `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT * FROM public.logs`:

[image]

So it looks like the server's going to execute this in about 6 ms. I guess that means all the overhead is in pgAdmin III, but how is SSMS able to do this so much faster?

Comment: Does this table have heavy `UPDATE` or `DELETE` traffic?

Comment: Are you running both SQL Server and PostgreSQL concurrently on your machine? How much RAM does you machine have?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually iterating through the entire resultset in both cases?  Or is it possible that you're only fetching the first x rows in SQL Server for instance?  And if PostgreSQL is not running locally, then there is no doubt that this is not a fair comparison.

Comment: What client are you using to benchmark your query? Do you display or dump the results somewhere? Is your disk fragmented? I've been using SQL Server and PostgreSQL for years, and I can certify you that PostgreSQL is usually much faster than SQL Server. Something's wrong here.

Comment: You posted PostgreSQL DDL but not the SQL Server DDL.  Perhaps differences might provide insight into performance differences.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` for the query. But you are essentially benchmarking the performance of your SQL client to display 50000 rows, **not** the performance of the server (and a simple `select * from..` isn't a good way to test performance anyway)

Comment: If your data types are indication of the actual content, your rows have 5kB+ each, which amounts to 250+ MB for the whole table. A typical simple table would have a couple of million rows to amount to as much. Since it's all text, your client will be hard put to it to render all of it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I agree - it's not a production use-case, but doesn't instill confidence in Postgres.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. - I'm using pgAdmin III

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Is there a better way to benchmark my Postres server?

Comment: Like @a_horse told you, it's (most likely) mostly taking most of the time, not Postgres. Your question is largely undefined so far, because *"it takes 40 seconds"* hardly defines what you are measuring. To see the server's share of the 40 seconds test with `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT * FROM  public.logs;` Consider [instructions for Postgres performance questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: According to the execution plan running the statement **on the server** only takes 7ms. so it is indeed pgAdmin that simply takes so long to _display_ the data (and probably some network overhead as well).

Comment: @J-DawG I have updated your answer with an easier way to do benchmarks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much for everyone's help in talking me down from the cliff:)

I composed a node console app app that puts my concerns to bed. In fact, my Postres instance beats SQL Server by about 50% (as @Guillaume F. pointed out). In the same client here are the results:

> Postres (RDS) query duration: 7062ms
>
> Postres (RDS) rows returned: 50000
>
> Postgres (Local) query duration: 1919ms
>
> Postgres (Local) rows returned: 46154
>
> MSSQL (local) query duration: 4681ms
>
> MSSQL (local) rows returned: 50000

Here's the sample app if anyone's interested in duplicating my results in their own environment:

```
'use strict';

let pgp = require('pg-promise')();
let db = pgp("postgres://username:password@server:5432/db");
let localdb = pgp("postgres://username:password@server:5432/db");
var mssql = require('mssql');

let start = new Date();
db.query('select * from logs').then((result) => {
    console.log("Postres (RDS) query duration: " + (new Date() - start) + "ms");
    console.log("Postres (RDS) rows returned: " + result.length);
    console.log("");

    let localstart = new Date();
    localdb.query('select * from logs').then((localresult) => {
        console.log("Postgres (Local) query duration: " + (new Date() - localstart) + "ms");
        console.log("Postgres (Local) rows returned: " + localresult.length);
        console.log("");

        var config = {
            user: 'username',
            password: 'password',
            server: 'server', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance 
            database: 'db'
        };

        mssql.connect(config).then(function () {

            // Query 
            let localMSSqlStart = new Date();
            new mssql.Request().query('select TOP 50000 * from dbo.AppLog ORDER BY 1 DESC').then(function (recordset) {
                console.log("MSSQL (local) query duration: " + (new Date() - localMSSqlStart) + "ms");
                console.log("MSSQL (local) rows returned: " + result.length);
                console.log("");
            }).catch(function (err) {

                // ... query error checks
                console.log("Problem querying MSSQL: " + err);
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {

            // ... connect error checks 
            console.log("Problem connecting to MSSQL: " + err);
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** (by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) author)

On a side note, this is just to show how to benchmark PostgreSQL in a more civilized way:

```
let pgp = require('pg-promise')();
let db = pgp("postgres://username:password@server:5432/db");
let localdb = pgp("postgres://username:password@server:5432/db");

db.result('select * from logs')
    .then(r => {
        console.log("Postres (RDS) rows returned:", r.rows.length);
        console.log("Postres (RDS) query duration:", r.duration + 'ms\n');
        return localdb.result('select * from logs')
            .then(r => {
                console.log("Postgres (Local) rows returned:", r.rows.length);
                console.log("Postgres (Local) query duration:", r.duration + 'ms\n');
            })
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The advantage of using method [result](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.result) for benchmarks is that [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) automatically extends the [Result](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/result.js#L14) with property `duration`.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t. I am grateful for your work on pg-promise as well. Awesome module!

Answer (score 3):

As we suspected, and as we can see from the `EXPLAIN` output, almost none of the time is spent on the server, but for transfer (network latency) and rendering the output. We see 7 ms in the `EXPLAIN` output you added to the question.

Rendering large amounts of text in pgAdmin III is not very fast. Two hints:

1. Most of the time, you don't need to see all the content of huge columns. To speed things up, you can set a maximum number of display characters In pgAdmin III. But don't get confused if you only see the leading fragment of long strings:

   - [Why are query results shortened in pgAdmin 1.18.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52926/3684)
2. pgAdmin 4 beta 2 is out (2016-6-24). Not release yet, but since it's a complete rewrite performance may be substantially different. [More on project's site.](https://www.pgadmin.org/)